# Is there a DbBulkCopy class in ADO.NET?

Tags: ado.net, enterprise-library

I'm just puzzled that I didn't find it. Our solution uses enterprise library data access application block to make it database agnostic. That means we rely heavily on classes from System.Data.Common. Now I have to implement bulk copy operations and there is no common class or interface that they implement.

I have checked implementation for our three main database vendors (Sql server, Informix and Oracle) and they all have bulk copy classes and their interfaces are almost the same.

Do I have to make my own interfaces in our framework to do database agnostic bulk copy operations? Am I missing something here?

Something like:

```
public class DbBulkCopy
{
    SqlBulkCopy sqlServer;
    OracleBulkCopy oracle;
    IfxBulkCopy informix;

    public void WriteToServer(DataTable table)
    {
        if (sqlServer != null) sqlServer.WriteToServer(table);
        if (oracle != null) oracle.WriteToServer(table);
        if (informix != null) informix.WriteToSerber(table);
    }
```

Comment: No, I don't think you are missing anything.  There doesn't appear to be a common interface.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much.